# Make my 1:5 clock stop when Space is being hold

Tags: javascript

I've created [this clock](http://andrebertel.com/mbb/started/), that should pause while SPACE is being hold. But my Js skills is extremely bad, so I got kinda lost. The clock is 1 to 5 clock. Which means every second that passes, 5 seconds passes in the clock.

```js
        var clock = new Clock("clock");
        clock.start();

        function Clock(id) {
            var clock = this;
            var timeout;
            var time;

            this.hours = 7;
            this.minutes = 10;
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.stop = stop;
            this.start = start;
            var isStarted = true;

function Click () {
if (isStarted) {
stop();
}
else
{
start();
}
}


            var element = document.getElementById(id);

            function stop() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }

            function start() {
                timeout = setTimeout(tick, 0);
                time = Date.now();
            }

            function tick() {
                time += 1000;
                timeout = setTimeout(tick, time - Date.now());
                display();
                update();
            }

            function display() {
                var hours = clock.hours;
                var minutes = clock.minutes;
                var seconds = clock.seconds;

                hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : "" + hours;
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : "" + minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : "" + seconds;

                element.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            }

            function update() {
                var seconds = clock.seconds += 5;

                if (seconds === 60) {
                    clock.seconds = 0;
                    var minutes = ++clock.minutes;

                    if (minutes === 60) {
                        clock.minutes = 0;
                        var hours = ++clock.hours;

                        if (hours === 24) clock.hours = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Awesome document title =) ASCII loaders are the best.

Comment: You're looking for events `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` and probably a `paused` flag inside `tick()`. (My fav function name too!)

Comment: Ye. But I have no idea how to use them in this case :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Something with spacebar: key events (probably `keypress`, that's the best)
- Something with **holding** spacebar: no keypress, but `keydown` and `keyup`
- Something with pausing a timer: clearing + resetting OR a pause flag

Update the timer/ticker so it only ticks when not paused:

```
var paused = false;
function tick() {
    time += 1000;
    timeout = setTimeout(tick, time - Date.now());
    if ( !paused ) {
        display();
        update();
    }
}
```

And then set the `paused` flag:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 32 ) {
        paused = true;
    }
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    paused = true;
}
```

I'm not sure about the timing, because you're using `Date.now()` and `setTimeout`, so maybe this'll make it jump after `onkeyup`. I'm sure you can figure that part out. It's your code after all.

Your 'class' has a very strange scope, so `tick` doesn't have access to the object properties via `this`. Example shows with public methods changing private property: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/tej4pvm9/1/

If you want to make a class, you should use JS prototype, so `this` works and you don't redefine new private methods for every instance: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/tej4pvm9/2/

Comment: So it's ending up like something like this: http://pastebin.com/zTTsqTCx
File updated to that: www.andrebertel.com/mbb/started

Comment: You have 2 `tick` functions. And adding event listeners in an object constructor is usually not a good idea.